# Displaying results from mysql database in a html/php table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I've got a page where I can view data output from a mysql database.  It works good.  But it's not stylish.  So I decided to put in a html `<table>` tag.  However it's not displaying the data.

I've tried putting in

`<td>  </td>` etc between rows but it stops the code being parsed.

```
<?php
    $servername = "******";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "********";
    $dbname = "test2";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM person_list";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);



    //display table
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>";

           if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo
     "<br>   ". $row["first_name"]. " "
                                   . $row["last_name"] ." "
                                    . $row["email"] ." " ;
        }
    }
     else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use the '<br>' tag, each '<tr>' (table row), will make a new row. You've declared three columns (th) in your header, so the body of your table need to have three columns too. Try Narendra Sisodia answer, it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, if it works for you..

```
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>";

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>". $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row["email"] . "</td> " ;
       echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be intrested in the foreach way.

Foreach would be quicker in larger data sets, but this is very similar to Narendrasingh Sisodia answer.

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>";
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["email"] . "</td> " ;
        echo "</tr>";
     }
}
echo "</table>";
```