# Viewing all of table with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have pretty limited knowledge when it comes to mysql. Usually when dealing with content on our site, I'm used to loading it from expressionengine, our cms, which I know fine. But recently I have to update this page that loads its data directly from our database. I took a course on mysql a while back, but I still don't really know how to use it.

The page doesn't need to use too much information, its basically just a list of awards presented to different businesses. I assume the table on the database just has a column for Business name, City, Year, and Type of award won. Stuff like that.

Now accessing the database doesn't seem like it would be too hard, and I feel like I could google around and find what I need. But to get started, I would just like to see the actual table! Why is it so complicated of a procedure to do?

The code on the file that I'm working on was set up like this to access the database:

```
$user_name = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$password  = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$server    = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$database  = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    $conni = new mysqli($server, $user_name, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("<center>
        <strong>No connection to database possible!<br />
        Please contact us!</strong>
        </center>");
        exit();
    }
```

I figured out how to view all tables on the database, by doing this:

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables"); 
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo($table[0] . "<BR>");   
}
```

So I know the name of the table I'm dealing with. I found a way to see all the column names:

```
$query = "select * from my_tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);

for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
    $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    echo $columnnames . "<br>";
}
```

But I still can't find how to just display the table itself. I might be thinking about this wrong, or not have the full idea, but what I want is a simple way to display the entire table, like with an html table. How can that be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942989/displaying-results-from-mysql-database-in-a-html-php-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961388/display-php-array-result-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the `<thead>` of a table with the column names you have above, however to display the results in a table format, use the `mysql_fetch_row` function on the `$result` of `SELECT * FROM my_tablename`. To reuse the `$result` after you've got the field names as in your last block, use `mysql_data_seek`:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

And then you can iterate through your results to get the contents of the table:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

`mysql_fetch_row` will get a numerically indexed array with where each value is the column value in MySQL, therefore by running foreach you get the value of each column. Put it inside of a `<td>`, wrap it all in a `<tr>` and you have yourself a table!

Just for good measure, you should switch to using `mysqli` in PHP as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated in later versions. To switch over, use the PHP documentation to search for the `mysql_` functions you're currently using, there will be a pink message which will direct you to the `mysqli` equivalents

Comment: I tried switching to the mysqli() functions, but it isn't working. Is all I'm supposed to do swap the function name and it should work just fine?